# C# & XML - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, visual-studio-2010

Good Evening StackOverFlowers, 
I have recently starting coding in XML via Visual Studio 2010. I have come across what seems to be a simple solution, yet the solution escapes me. I get an error for an Object Reference not set, but I don't see what I haven't set. (error here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDZgG.png )

My codebehind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Xml;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
    int intDVDID;
    XmlDocument myXmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
    XmlNode rootNode;
    XmlNode selectedDVD;

public void Page_Load(object Src, EventArgs E)
{
    intDVDID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);

    myXmlDocument.Load(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + @"dvd.xml");
    rootNode = myXmlDocument.DocumentElement;
    selectedDVD = rootNode.ChildNodes[intDVDID - 1];
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        rootNode.RemoveChild(selectedDVD);
        myXmlDocument.Save(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + @"dvd.xml");
        lblMessage.Text = "You have successfully deleted the DVD";
    }
  }
}
```

Is it just a matter of saying:

```
  int intDVDID = new intDVDID
```

I know by reading this you're all going to want to pull your hair out at my inexperience and lack of understanding how to solve this, but I appreciate your time and your patience just looking.

Best regards,
Laura :)

Edit: 
Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- This XML document describes a DVD library -->
<library>
  <DVD id="1">
    <title>Breakfast at Tiffany's</title>
    <format>Movie</format>
    <genre>Classic</genre>
  </DVD>
  <DVD id="2">
    <title>Contact</title>
    <format>Movie</format>
    <genre>Science fiction</genre>
  </DVD>
  <DVD id="3">
    <title>Little Britain</title>
    <format>TV Series</format>
    <genre>Comedy</genre>
  </DVD>
</library>
```

Comment: What does `dvd.xml` look like?

Comment: Edited to add XML. Thanks for the ask Climbage!

Comment: What's the value of `id` when you get this error?

Comment: It was 1. I'm not sire what was going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is looking like your selectedDVD may null, put some null checks to verify.

```
if(selectedDVD != null)
{
}
```

Edit: In response to your question in comments. Here is some example code. I threw in an xpath even though it seems your case is very simple you may want to use this in the future

```
string xml = "<xml><node id='1'></node><node id='2'></node></xml>";

XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);           

//This is an xpath(This replaces your .DocumentElement.ChildNodes[index]
XmlNode desiredNode = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("node[@id='1']");
if (desiredNode != null)
{
    xmlDoc.DocumentElement.RemoveChild(desiredNode);
}//if
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I'm going to test this now. I appreciate your patience.

Comment: Okay, so I popped in some Null checks and I still get the same result. In the change of making myself look ridiculously more stupid than I already have... do to a null check, I just do something like this?:

`        if (selectedDVD != null)
        {
            selectedDVD = rootNode.ChildNodes[intDVDID - 1];
        } `

Comment: Thank you so much Brian. I truly appreciate the help. You're a star!

Answer (score 0):

Pleaase make sure that your query string is not empty it may cause you null reference exeption that you are geting.

```
if(Request.QueryString["id"]!="")
{
    intDVDID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Cold Told! You're help was fantastic. Helped me solve some issues. Much appreciated!